# How to send and receive over serial with circuitpython

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do a resource monitor with some neopixels and wanted to know how to send a string over serial and have my gemma m0 listen for that string. Sorry if I used the wrong terminology, pretty new to this.

Comment: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-gemma-m0/circuitpython-uart-serial-2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through the help center, in particular [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

for me works as following:

```
import supervisor

while True:
    if supervisor.runtime.serial_bytes_available:
        value = input().strip()
        # Sometimes Windows sends an extra (or missing) newline - ignore them
        if value == "":
            continue
        else:
            print(value)
```